# Android: How to avoid blue (focussed) buttons in dialogs?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i have some blue buttons in some of my UI dialogs, like:

[Image http://freigabe.philweb.de/bubblr/20120724_dialog_blue-button.png](http://freigabe.philweb.de/bubblr/20120724_dialog_blue-button.png)

how can i avoid that the buttons have focus?
i tried some things like `messageBox.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();`
but evrything crashed my app.

here is my code:

```
case askRudeMode:
{   
    messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    messageBox.setTitle(dialogSubject);
    messageBox.setMessage(dialogText);
    messageBox.setButton(bubblr.lang.getString("YES"), new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bubblr.prefs.setRudeMode(false);    //----- disable rudemode -> save to prefs
                bubblr.prefs.setAskRudeMode();
            }
        });
    }
});
messageBox.setButton2(bubblr.lang.getString("NO"), new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bubblr.prefs.setRudeMode(true); //----- enable rudemode -> save to prefs
                bubblr.prefs.setAskRudeMode();
            }
        });
    }
});

// messageBox.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();                                               // führt zu crash der app
//      if (messageBox.getCurrentFocus() != null) messageBox.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();    // funktioniert nicht :(

    messageBox.show();
    break;
}
```

other dialogs dont have focussed buttons....
why is that?

bye
phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following code after this call: "messageBox.show();"

```
Button button = (Button) messageBox.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
button.setFocusable(false);
```

This code avoids to focuse your first dialog button.

Comment: this does not work:      
Button button1 = (Button) messageBox.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
button1.setFocusable(true);
Button button2 = (Button) messageBox.findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
button2.setFocusable(true);

Comment: Just check my edit, You have to do setFocusable(false) and not "true". My bad, sorry.

Comment: now it is working . thanks!!! ..... but why do i have other dialogs that look the same and have no focussed buttons?

Comment: I don't know why. Are you using the emulator? Because if yes, sometimes it focus on one button with no reason. Or maybe you use a phone with a joystick and when you touch it, one button is focused. But these are just assumptions. (And if the answer corresponds about what are you waiting for, don't forget to accept it ;))

Answer (score 0):

instead of using only Button make use of positive and negative Buttons  as:

```
case askRudeMode:
{   
    messageBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    messageBox.setTitle(dialogSubject);
    messageBox.setMessage(dialogText);
    messageBox.setPositiveButton(bubblr.lang.getString("YES"), new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bubblr.prefs.setRudeMode(false);    //----- disable rudemode -> save to prefs
                bubblr.prefs.setAskRudeMode();
            }
        });
    }
});
messageBox.setNegativeButton(bubblr.lang.getString("NO"), new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bubblr.prefs.setRudeMode(true); //----- enable rudemode -> save to prefs
                bubblr.prefs.setAskRudeMode();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot use setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton methods on an AlertDialog object, but on a AlertDialog.Builder object.

Comment: how do i have to do it with an AlertDialog.Builder object? the code above fails with: The method setPositiveButton(String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type AlertDialog